# How to run python scripts from shell file without messing up directory paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, directory

I have a python script that loads data files using relative paths.
I then have a shell script from a parent directory that runs the python script like so

`automate.sh` contents:

```
python3 /path/to/python/file/file.py
```

`file.py` contents:

```
import numpy as np
np.loadtxt(./data/data2load.txt)
```

The problem is when I run this python script from the shell script, the relative path is broken. It tries to find the file to load in `/path/to/shell/script/data/data2load.txt`.
Is there a robust way to fix this without using absolute paths?

The fix I currently have is in my `automate.sh`, I instead write:

```
cd /path/to/python/file
python3 file.py
cd ../../../..
```

But this is obviuosly really tedious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "data/data2load.txt")
```

the value of `DATA_PATH` will now be `/path/to/python/file/data/data2load.txt`, so:

```
np.loadtxt(DATA_PATH)
```

should always load the correct file.

Comment: Thanks. Just to confirm, is `BASE_DIR` set to the directory that' calling the python script? In this case it's the directory of the shell script?

Comment: Yes, `__file__` is always set to the full path of the script itself therefore `BASE_DIR` will be the parent directory of the `.py` file.